# Converting UTC seconds to get hours of operation

Tags: javascript, utc

I'm not very familiar with UTC, but from what I do understand, it starts at 0 so I'm trying to understand how you wold convert a UTC time of +32400.  I've been told +32400 should equate to 9:00am UTC time, but I'm unclear on how that works.

I was trying something like this, but it's giving me, at the moment, 2am.

```
const dateIn = Date.now() + (day[1].openInSecondsUTC * 1000);
const dateInTimeStamp = new Date(dateIn);
```

Comment: what is `day` ? how it is initialized?

Comment: UTC is just a "clock" that is supposed to be a normed reference for time. Like a timezone if you want, but that doesn't suffer of any ambiguous problem / daylight saving change. "+32400" is not a UTC time, it's just a big number.

Comment: Really, the only thing you need to know is day[1].openInSecondsUTC equates to 32400.

Comment: @Pac0 weird, I was told that number should equal 9:00am.  I'm just unclear on how that works.

Comment: 22nd of October, 21h20 and some seconds is the current UTC time now. https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc . 32400 is likely supposed to represent a number of seconds. "seconds in UTC" does not mean anything, a duration in seconds is the same whether you look at an UTC date or another timezone

Comment: I understand things are unclear, maybe the most productive thing would be to explain what is the problem you want to solve, what do you want to achieve. What is your input and what do you want as output, beyond that UTC thing.

Comment: just for your information, 32400 is the number of seconds in 9h (9*60*60 === 32400).
So, if you take a date that has its time at 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds (midnight, beginning of day), and you add this number, you will indeed get 9 AM. However, it won't work every day, it won't work if it is a daylight saving day (like the next Sunday for some countries in Europe) on a timezone that uses them. That may be the reason where it is more correct to use the UTC datetime, so you will be guaranteed that this particular day at 0h 0min 0sec + 9hours will give you the same day at 9h00 AM

Comment: so "UTC starts at zero" is wrong. But you _can_ choose a UTC datetime that has its time at 00:00:00. Like any datetime. There is no such things as "seconds in UTC". You just have a big number of seconds that is representing a duration of 9 hours. If you want to be guaranteed to have consistent changes in time (from midnight to 9AM) if you add 9 hours, you should indeed use a UTC datetime as your basis for calculation. This "replaces" the timezone. Otherwise, 9 hours after midnight could be 8AM or 10AM some days when the daylight saving shift occurs.

Comment: @Pac0 to answer your above question, I was tasked to output store hours and was given the number 32400 as the open time.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, 32400 is your input. It is the  "time of store opening, expressed as seconds since midnight". To be clear again, it's not an "UTC" thing. However, if you use this value to create a datetime with the correct opening time (9AM), then you should indeed consider using a UTC datetime at midnight for doing so, to avoid the issues on daylight saving days (and other rare special adjustment dates). Note that I always talk about datetimes, date and time are always linked, even though the javascript type is called "date".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confounding the idea of UTC (Universal Time Coordinated) which is a common time reference as a time with a Unix time stamp which is a number of seconds.

What you are looking for is a Date object's value as a Unix timestamp (# seconds).

This code produces 9am.

As you see, the starting time is 00:00:00, so taking the unix time stamp (`.valueOf()`) and adding your seconds, then creating new date from that will produce the output.

```js
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
const nineAM = new Date(date.valueOf() + 32400000);
console.log(nineAM.toUTCString());
```

Comment: I saw it an fixed it,

Comment: So that's how it's done.  Thanks for your help and everyone's for the insight.

Comment: I do have one question... why does the variable nineAM show as 4am, but when you add toUTCString(), it changes to 9am?

Comment: Because using `.toUTCString()` outputs the time based upon the reference time that all other times are derived from. Outputing the date with any other `.toString` method will show the time in your timezone. You have complete control over the output of any date with JavaScript. You can/should use the [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) to format your dates in anyway you desire.